# Spring zuul proxy to OAuth2 server password grant

Tags: spring, proxy

I'm trying to implement a Zuul reverse proxy with @EnableOAuth2Sso so I can relay the access tokens obtained from the authentication server to my resource server.

The question is how do I configure the Zuul proxy to forward the username and password to the authentication server, since I am using the password grant flow to obtain the tokens.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this yet? Please share if you have found one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is still relevant...

I had a task to configure Authorization and Resource servers behind Zuul using password grant type.
This [article](http://lifeinide.com/post/2018-04-14-spring-oauth2-zuul-internal-external-client-workflow/) and [example on github](https://github.com/kakawait/uaa-behind-zuul-sample) helped me a lot, but mostly I've used debug to configure the environment.

Please check my [example of configuration OAuth2 Password Grant Type behind Zuul](https://github.com/netstalk3r/globalrep/tree/master/oauth2-password-behind-zuul).

To run the example, inside every service folder run `mnv spring-boot:run`

In browser go to http://localhost:8765, credentials user/user, admin/admin

http://localhost:8761/ - eureka

I have not used `@EnableOAuth2Sso`, but instead `@EnableOAuth2Client` and configure only `ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider` ([more details here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_manual)).
`@EnableOAuth2Sso` is configured all token providers, but I need only password provider.

Example uses JwtTokens.